# Multiple ListViews in Stack Widget, event separation

Tags: flutter

I have a Stack with 2 ListViews in a certain state of the app,
at this point, only the top list is handling gesture/pointer events

Is it possible to interact with the base list if it is visible on the viewport(if the top list doesn't take the whole screen, in the attached picture it means I want to be able to scroll the list that is represented by the blue area)?

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const CustomStackApp());
}

class CustomStackApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomStackApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: CustomStackHome(),
    );
  }
}

class CustomStackHome extends StatefulWidget {
  final StackBaseListView stackBaseListView = const StackBaseListView();
  const CustomStackHome({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomStackHome> createState() => _CustomStackHomeState();
}

class _CustomStackHomeState extends State<CustomStackHome> {
  bool toggle = false;

  void toggleFun() {
    setState(() {
      toggle = toggle ? false : true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text("Toggle"),
        actions: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: toggleFun,
            tooltip: 'Increment',
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          widget.stackBaseListView,
          toggle ?
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                color: Colors.white,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                ),
              );
            },
          )
              :
              Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StackBaseListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackBaseListView({super.key});

  Color getRandomColor() {
    Random random = Random();
    return Color.fromARGB(
        255, random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: 250,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            color: getRandomColor(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: tried to set top list's https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html to `true`?

Comment: Oh thanks, solves the problem